# How to access variable from owner instance?

Tags: java

An instance `a` of class `A` has an instance `b` of class `B`.

How can `b` access a variable of `a`?

```
class A {
    boolean flag;
    B b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }

    public A() {
        b = new B();
        b.doSomething();
        chageFlag();
        b.doSomething();
    }

    void changeFlag() {
        // do something with flag
    }
    // other stuff
}

class B {
    void doSomething() {
        // here I need to access a from the instance owning b.
        boolean aFlag = ?? // how to access a.flag ??
    }
}
```

Comment: `B` has no relationship to "owner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to access a variable of A in this instance because A and B have no parent/ child or outer/inner class relationship here.

The way to do this is to pass the instance of A to B, such as,

```
B b = new B(this);
```

For this you need to adjust the constructor to take in A as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is, `b` has no way of reaching `a`; simply because it does not have a reference to it.

If the two classes are so related that you need `b` to know about `a`, then you can make `B` an inner class in `A`:

```
class A {
    boolean flag;
    B b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }

    public A() {
        b = this.new B();
        b.doSomething();
        changeFlag();
        b.doSomething();
    }

    void changeFlag() {
    }

    class B {
        void doSomething() {
            boolean aFlag = flag;
        }
    }
}
```

`B.doSomething()` is able to read `flag` from the enclosing class because `B` is an inner class.

Be aware that this solution is not appropriate in all situations, it makes the coupling between the two classes even tighter.